# Does Oracle's Optimizer Take into Consideration a Subquery's Underlying Columns?

Tags: database, oracle, query-optimization, oracle12c

Say you have a query like so:

```
with subselect as (
   select foo_id 
     from foo
) 
select bar_id 
  from bar
  join subselect on foo_id = bar_id
 where foo_id = 1000
```

Imagine you have an index on foo_id. Is Oracle's database smart enough to use the index in the query for the line "where foo_id = 1000"? OR since foo_id is wrapped in a subquery, does Oracle lose the index information related to this column?

Comment: What does the plan indicate?

Comment: The query optimiser takes into account all columns in your query. What makes you think it's not? You can verify this by examining the query plan.

Comment: Somewhat impossible to answer with certainty (*maybe the optimiser will do a table scan because there are only 5 rows in the largest table and using indexes isn't worth the effort*) but there is no reason to assume because you use subqueries that the optimizer is too dumb to consider them.

Comment: The optimizer analyzes each bit of your query to determine a plan, and in newer versions will even change plans mid execution if it sees it has made a less than optimal decision. Sub queries aren't special...they're basically treated as any other 'regular' query. Using an index doesn't always make things better fwiw. Look at the execution plan to see how your subquery was treated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perform a simple test:

```
create table foo as
select t.object_id as foo_id, t.* from all_objects t;

create table bar as
select t.object_id as bar_id, t.* from all_objects t;

create index foo_id_ix on foo(foo_id);

exec dbms_stats.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(ownname=>user, tabname=>'FOO', method_opt=>'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS' );

explain plan for 
with subselect as (
   select foo_id 
     from foo
) 
select bar_id 
  from bar
  join subselect on foo_id = bar_id
 where foo_id = 1000;

 select * from table( DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY );
```

and a result of last query is:

```
Plan hash value: 445248211

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation            | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |           |     1 |    10 |   366   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   1 |  MERGE JOIN CARTESIAN|           |     1 |    10 |   366   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS FULL  | BAR       |     1 |     5 |   365   (1)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |   BUFFER SORT        |           |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN  | FOO_ID_IX |     1 |     5 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   2 - filter("BAR_ID"=1000)
   4 - access("FOO_ID"=1000)
```

In the above example Oracle uses `|*  4 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN` using index: `FOO_ID_IX` for filter `4 - access("FOO_ID"=1000)`
So the answer is:
 **yes, the Oracle's database is smart enough to use the index in the query for the line "where foo_id = 1000"**